# How do I use a global auth function declared in a Zustand store?

Tags: react-native, firebase-authentication, zustand

I am trying to keep a user logged in my application by setting the **authState** in a zustand store in my **LoginScreen** I use my **globally declared login function**, however I get a **typeError** saying:

> LOG  Error:  [TypeError: undefined is not a function]

Here is my store code:

```js
import { create } from 'zustand';
import { auth } from '../firebase';

const useAuthStore = create((set) => ({
  user: null,

  checkAuthState: () => {
    return auth.onAuthStateChanged((user) => {
      if (user) {
        set({ user });
      } else {
        set({ user: null });
      }
    });
  },

  login: async (email, password) => {
    try {
      const userCredential = await auth.signInWithEmailAndPassword(email, password);
      const user = userCredential.user;
      set({ user });
      return user;
    } catch (error) {
      console.log('Error: ', error);
      throw error;
    }
  },

  logout: async () => {
    try {
      await auth.signOut();
      set({ user: null });
    } catch (error) {
      console.log('Error: ', error);
      throw error;
    }
  },
}));

export default useAuthStore;
```

I console logged said function in my LoginScreen an it returned me, which proves that the function is defined?

> LOG  login content:  [Function login]

here is my LoginScreen handleLogin function:

```js
const handleLogin = async () => {
  try {
    console.log("login content:", login)
    await login(email, password);
    console.log('logged in successfully')
  } catch (err) {
    setError(err.message);
  }
};
```

I do not understand why I get the error

Answer (score 0):

One possible reason for this error is that you are not correctly importing the login function from your useAuthStore store in your LoginScreen component.

And In login page

```
import useAuthStore from '../path/to/useAuthStore';

const LoginScreen = () => {
  const { login } = useAuthStore();
  //=== rest
}
```

and about handle login

```
const handleLogin = async () => {
  try {
    await login(email, password);
    console.log('logged in successfully')
  } catch (err) {
    setError(err.message);
  }
};
```

Make sure that you have correctly imported the useAuthStore hook in your component and that you are using it to get access to the login function.